# persistence works only in "ugly way"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I have a curious case with javaEE persistence.

**Here are the codes don't work, but by my best knowledge it should:**

in the parent:

```
private List<GyOBHatarozat> hatarozatok;

@OneToMany(
  mappedBy = "orokbefGyermek",
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
  orphanRemoval = true)
public List<GyOBHatarozat> getHatarozatok() {
  return hatarozatok;
}

public void setHatarozatok(List<GyOBHatarozat> hatarozatok) {
  this.hatarozatok = hatarozatok;
}
```

in child:

```
//no annotation
private GyGyermek orokbefGyermek;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "OROKBEF_GYERMEK_ID")
public GyGyermek getOrokbefGyermek() {
  return orokbefGyermek;
}
```

**And here is the code which works:**

in the parent:

```
private List<GyOBHatarozat> hatarozatok;

@OneToMany(
  mappedBy = "orokbefGyermek",
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
  orphanRemoval = true)
public List<GyOBHatarozat> getHatarozatok() {
  return hatarozatok;
}

public void setHatarozatok(List<GyOBHatarozat> hatarozatok) {
  this.hatarozatok = hatarozatok;
}
```

in child:

```
@ManyToOne
private GyGyermek orokbefGyermek;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "OROKBEF_GYERMEK_ID")
public GyGyermek getOrokbefGyermek() {
  return orokbefGyermek;
}
```

If I move all the annotation to field: doesn't work, if I move all to the getter, doesn't work. If I delete the ManyToOne annotation on getter, but leave it on field, doesn't work.

Can anybody explain this strange behaviour of JPA annotations? I couldn't find any useful clue.

Comment: I think you will need to expand on 'doesn't work' and post the full code of both entities (in the case it is not working)  if you want an answer.

Comment: @AlanHay I will update the question, I got some ASAP work